# How does this method of "ajax uploader" get around the same origin policy?

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

The method on this page: http://www.ajaxf1.com/demo/ajaxupload/ uses a form w/a target of an iframe, and an action of a page that returns a JS function that targets the original page. How does this work?

So orginal->target: iframe, action: post page; then iframe gets a JS function that->targets: original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using ajax, it's actually an old trick to post a form without reloading the page.

What's being actually reloaded is the iframe, then you get the response out of it via JS.

Comment: Yep got that part - but how does it not violate the same origin policy? Also just to be clear to anyone trying to learn from this I understand its not ajax

Comment: Because the iframe is in the same page, in the same site

Answer (score 0):

iFrames are like page elements that you can embed into other pages. they have a browse url different from the parent page. so the url of the iframe will be your crossdomain url and since the iframe is on the same page you can access the response from the iframe refer this one http://ajaxpatterns.org/IFrame_Call